# How to exclude a jar from dependent war only for running test in pom

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

Sorry if this issue is simple, I tried a lot,but couldnot able to find a solution.

I have a project Project A. In pom.xml of this war project, I have one dependent project which I added as the depedency in pom.xml. Till now everything is fine.

This how I did this in pom.xml of parent project Project A:

```
 <dependency>
       <groupId>com.abc.rules</groupId> 
       <artifactId>rules-common</artifactId> 
       <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version> 
  </dependency>
```

Funtionality is working fine after running build

But when I tried to run testcases of parent project Project A, it is not working.

Then I tried this in pom.xml and it worked:

```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.abc.rules</groupId> 
           <artifactId>rules-common</artifactId> 
           <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version> 
          -<exclusions> 
             -<exclusion> <groupId>org.sonatype.sisu</groupId>
                          <artifactId>sisu-guava</artifactId> 
              </exclusion> 
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
```

But I may affect my funtionality.

So what I need is that, I need to exclude `sisu-guava.jar` for running testcases of my parent project Project A. But it shouldnot be excluded as I did above.

And I cannot do any changes on pom.xml of `rules-common` war project. How can I do relevent changes in pom.xml of project A?

Someone please help me out.

Comment: what kind of issue do you meet? In other words, what do you mean by "it is not working"?

Comment: I am getting reflective class issue like version resolver cannot be cast to default version resolver. So conflicts while running junit test.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in you pom

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abc.rules</groupId> 
            <artifactId>rules-common</artifactId> 
            <exclusions> 
              <exclusion> 
                <groupId>org.sonatype.sisu</groupId>
                <artifactId>sisu-guava</artifactId> 
              </exclusion> 
           </exclusions>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Or you will have to use profile to exclude the dependency in some case

Comment: Then use profiles to exclude the transitive dependency during your tests